# Почему три строки <table> уходят вправо?

Tags: css, table

https://codepen.io/yasakova/pen/vYRwXeK
Как исправить?

```
<tr>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="title row">
            <th rowspan="3" class="title line3"> Past Perfect</th>
            <th rowspan="3" class="title line3"> Present Perfect</th>
            <th rowspan="3" class="title line3"> Perfect</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
            <td>Alexa23</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Во-первых, th - это table head, эти ячейки не должны располагаться внутри, они должны быть в самом верху. Во-вторых, зачем Вам rowspan="3" (из-за которого всё и съезжает)? Вы знаете, что это вообще такое и как оно работает?

Comment: хорошо, поняла  .

Comment: @humster_spb, *"эти ячейки не должны располагаться внутри, они должны быть в самом верху"* Это неверное утверждение.